# Load multipe sharepoint list item fields in one Go using CSOM c#

Tags: linq, sharepoint, lambda, csom

```
       ***ctx.Load(listItemCollection,
       eachItem => eachItem.Include(
        item => item,
        item => item["Column1"],
      item => item["Column2"]
      ));***
```

i have list of fields in a array of string instead of column1 and column2, how can i pass it through in include linq, not able to create proper lambda on runtime. i tried following ways but couldn't get success. Static befor loops works but thw fields added in loop fails as it doesn't evaluate string value in loop

```
      ***Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] paramss = new 
       Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[length];
      paramss[0] = x => x.ContentType;
       paramss[1] = x => x["Title"]; 
      count = 2;
   foreach (string item in solConnDefModel.Columns)
    { paramss[count] = x => x[item]; 
       count++;
     }***
```

Comment: What LINQ code? There's no LINQ code in the question, just expressions that read fields from an already loaded ListItem. All SharePoint APIs allow field selection, even the server-side model, simply because reading an entire list item is *too expensive* even on the server

Comment: And all start with passing the list of fields as strings. LINQ was added later, as a convenience API.

Comment: In fact LINQ queries are converted to *CAML*. The expressions you try to use to specify fields are still converted into CAML. So instead of trying to use strings to build expressions to build strings, just pass the strings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have to create lambda expression at runtime. following code i was able to get expected value

Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] paramss = new Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[length];

```
 foreach (string item in Columns)
   {
  if (item.ToLower() != "contenttype")
   {
   ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ListItem), "x");
       var propertyInfo = typeof(ListItem).GetMethod("get_Item");                
     
     var arguments = new List<Expression> { Expression.Constant(item) };
      var expression = Expression.Call(parameter, propertyInfo, arguments);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ListItem, object>>(expression, parameter);
        paramss[count] = lambda;

     }
     else
     {
         paramss[count] = x => x.ContentType;
     }
   count++;
       }
```

Comment: If you have to write so much code, you're doing it wrong. You didn't post any LINQ codde either, that's just expressions that do ... something. CSOM isn't just LINQ, so if you want something more dynamic than LINQ (btw *what do you want?*) you can use the rest of the API

Comment: All SharePoint APIs allow specifying the fields as strings, even the server-side model, because retrieving a single list item is too expensive. Fields are stored in an entity-attribute-value-like schema, so retrieving even a single item requires a lot of work and parsing of encoded fields.

Comment: Worst case, you could write the CAML query generated by the expressions yourself. Or you could use [the OData API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#select-fields-to-return) and specify the field names in the `select` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Please take a reference of below code:

```
List dlist = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listname");

context.Load(dlist);
context.ExecuteQuery();


string[] fieldNames = { "Id", "Title", "num", "mStartDate" };
// Create the expression used to define the fields to be included
List<Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>> fieldsToBeIncluded = new List<Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>>();                       

foreach (string s in fieldNames)
{
    fieldsToBeIncluded.Add(items => items.Include(item => item[s]));
}

// Initialize the collection of list items         

var listItems = dlist.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
context.Load(listItems, fieldsToBeIncluded.ToArray());
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can hover on `load` method to see what type parameter it requires, then generate a corresponding one and pass it.

Comment: i tried this but in loop item => item[s], s was not being replaces as string s was like getvalue(classname.method..)    ..i have to create Expression ..i was able to do it, just posting the answer.

Comment: @AnilArora why replace anything? Those expressions are converted to CAML. Only CAML is sent to the server, so if you want to create a query by specifying field names, build the CAML query.